# call JS function only once

Tags: javascript

I'm working with the following function which runs fine but I only want to call it once - currently every time I use scroll, the function id triggered and as a result my animated charts get re-built.

```
window.onscroll = function() {


new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData);




}
```

thanks!!!!

Comment: "I only want to call it once"; why do you use onscroll then?

Comment: Well... Just replacing `window.onscroll` with `window.onload` will do. :)

Comment: I simply want the charts to be animated when user scrolls the page to the div where they sit. is there a better way??

Comment: Basically the charts are far down the page and i want them to load only when user scrolls down so they see animation. window.onload will animate charts before user gets to see them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isNotScrolled = true;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if(isNotScrolled)
  {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
    new Chart(document.getElementById("radar").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData);

    isNotScrolled = false;
  }
}
```

You may also consider using [jQuery with waypoint plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600108/is-there-a-javascript-event-that-triggers-when-an-html-element-scrolls-into-view), that may help you doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Changed in if(), nice... +1 Hahahaaaaaa ;)